# Flutter application crashes on start no error in log-cat accept few warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, flutter

i am using Android Studio for developing flutter application. It was working fine when i have start development few days back. But when i delete app and re-install it, it will crashes several time and after trying many times it start working all of sudden not sure what is the problem.

I am so unsure what is happening....

> For details what i am doing on it are:

1. I am using native code to run and broadcast data from location
2. List item service. I am using database Sqflite in which i am storing data.
3. i am getting location updates every 30 seconds and storing them.

Please suggest if any one have any idea what is happening feel free to ask questions

> Warning:
>
> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve
>   target intent service, skipping classname enforcement 12-17
>    E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering
>   the message: ServiceIntent not found.

But code is working once it stop crashing, i am in doubt that these warning are coming from different apps.

Comment: Do you use Firebase for what? Do you use `android_alarm_manger` package?

Comment: @shadowsheep. i have used background service and broadcast receiver.....
today i have reinstall it again it is working fine now but if i delete it and reinstall it it will create issue....

Comment: @shadowsheep, i have used timer.

Comment: I've asked you that because of this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25417 It seems to have some things in common but I don't know if it's your case.

Comment: Thanks, i am not using this one !

Comment: Anyway is very strange that you cannot see the stacktrace in AS logcat. Could I suggest you to add Firebase Crashlytics to your app so that when it crashes you receive a mail and see the log on Firebase Crashlytics console. In this way you could have a deep inside of what is going wrong with your application?

Comment: Sure i will try it, Thank you for investing your time on it.